# Set write permissions for all users for my program folder

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, windows-xp, setup-project

I have build a program in Visual Studio. The program creates a logfile and writes into it while the program is running. Therefore I constructed an installer (setup-project), that should set write permissions for my program-folder regardless which user works with the program.
currently it looks like this:

```
// ...
}
  InitializeComponent();

  string folder = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

  DirectorySecurity ds = Directory.GetAccessControl(folder);
  ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone",   //Everyone is important
                                                  //because rights for all users!
   FileSystemRights.Read | FileSystemRights.Write, AccessControlType.Allow));
}
// ...
```

In the last two rows I get a `System.SystemException`: “Die Vertrauensstellung zwischen der primären Domäne und der vertrauenswürdigen Domäne konnte nicht hergestellt werden.“

[Translation: "The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain could not be established."]

The stacktrace reads like this:

```
bei System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.TranslateToSids(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Boolean& someFailed)
bei System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean& someFailed)
bei System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess)
bei System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(Type targetType)
bei System.Security.AccessControl.CommonObjectSecurity.ModifyAccess(AccessControlModification modification, AccessRule rule, Boolean& modified)
bei System.Security.AccessControl.CommonObjectSecurity.AddAccessRule(AccessRule rule)
bei System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity.AddAccessRule(FileSystemAccessRule rule)
```

Have you an idea what I can do?
thanks

Comment: Did you execute your installer with administrative privilges?

Comment: Note that there is a reason for the various public folders on a given system for storing program data...

Comment: Oh, I thought execute the installer with administrative privilges is a default setting. Where can I looking for this? In the properties of my setup project I can´t find this.

Comment: Now I checked the code in my admin-account and I get again this Exception. The program shall be installed by users with administrativ permissions. How can I set the write permission without I get this Exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the best answer isn't what you've asked for.  There's a good reason for not writing to the program files directory.  Log data in particular is transient and shouldn't be written here.

It's a much better idea to write log data to the directory specified by the TEMP environment variable.  If you do this you'll save your users a few troubles and prevent them cursing your software in the future.  Please check out this answer which covers the same topic:

[Allow access permission to write in Program Files of Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946420/allow-access-permission-to-write-in-program-files-of-windows-7)

Answer (score 3):

Aren't you missing the statement where you actually set the access control back to the directory?

```
Directory.SetAccessControl(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), ds);
```

Answer (score 0):

This [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131666/vista-and-programdata) should point you in the right direction. Basically, you do **NOT** want any user writing to the `Program Files` folder. UAC, security and other measures are there to try and prevent this as much as possible.

Essentially, if you want a single file which will be written to by all users, you will want it in the `ProgramData` folder, accessible through the `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%`, rather than the individual users' temporary folder, which is definitely what you want to do with a log file. Remember that the temporary folder's content should be considered volatile, and could be deleted at any time, such as by the Disk Cleanup Wizard.